# How to count instances of any Unicode letter in my string

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, count

Using Ruby 2.4,  how do I count the number of instances of a Unicode letter in my string?  I'm trying:

```
2.4.0 :009 > string = "a"
 => "a"
2.4.0 :010 > string.count('\p{L}')
 => 0
```

but it's displaying 0, and it should be returning 1.

I want to use the above expression rather than "a-z" because "a-z" won't cover things like accented e's.

Comment: Can you try with `scan` and `count`? `string.scan(/\p{L}/).count`

Comment: That returns the expected result.  Thanks

Comment: "it should be returning 1" – Why? According to the documentation, you are counting the number of `'\'`s, `'p'`s, `'{'`s, `'L'`s, and `'}'`s. There are none, ergo, it should be returning `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `String#scan`, passing your `\p{L}` regex, and then chain the `count` method:

```
string = "aá"
p string.scan(/\p{L}/).count
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that does not create a temporary array.

```
str = "Même temps l'année prochaine."

str.size - str.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/, '').size
  #=> 24
```

The POSIX bracket expression `[[:alpha:]]` is the same as `\p{Alpha}` (aka `\p{L}`).
Note that

```
str.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/, '')
  #=> "  ' ."
```